# How many points do I have to reach to get a service star as infantry?

Tags: battlefield-4

I want to calculate how many points I have left to reach my next service star for each class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scores you have to reach to earn a service star for the corresponding class are as follows:

- Assault = 155.000
- Engineer = 131.000
- Support = 134.000
- Recon = 104.000
- Commander = 20.000

Comment: Huh. I wonder why Assault is higher.